# Oauth2 refresh token gives org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

I have configured the OAuth2 authorization server and resource server using spring-cloud-starter-oauth2.  The authorization server uses JdbcTokenStore to persist the token (I still have the "Failed to find refresh token for token xxxx" message which seems to be a bug).  However, the thing that I wish to resolve here is:

I am able to request for a new token and use it to fetch data from the resource server.  However, once the token expires, I cannot refresh the token using the given refresh token.

Using curl:

```
curl -XPOST foo:secret@localhost:9009/myauthserver/oauth/token  -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token=4187f090-a355-4613-bc17-2e4565ffdc0b
```

will return:

{"error":"server_error","error_description":"The given id must not be null!; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!"}

At the backend, the error is:

> 2017-02-20 15:47:31.058  WARN 11152 --- [nio-9009-exec-9]
>   .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused
>   by Handler execution:
>   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: The given
>   id must not be null!; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!

The interesting thing is if I give an invalid token, it actually returns

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid refresh token: 4187f090-a355-4613-bc17-2e4565ffdcee"}